# Weird flickering screen Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, screen

Recently, while simply browsing my computer, my screen automatically starts flickering like below. This has happened more than five times in the past three days. Once this happens, pressing any key has no effect and I am forced to force shutdown the computer. Fortunately, I am able to start it again.

Can anyone guess why might this be happening?

I have even tried a fresh install of the Operating System (Ubuntu 20.04.02) by following the option - **erasing disk and reinstalling Ubuntu**.

EDIT:

```sh
$ ls -al /boot

total 133396
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Apr 25 14:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root     4096 Apr 25 14:32 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248291 Feb  5 14:48 config-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   248245 Apr 13 00:17 config-5.8.0-50-generic
drwx------  3 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Apr 25 14:43 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Apr 25 14:42 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 52051892 Apr 25 14:42 initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 52906871 Apr 25 14:43 initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       27 Apr 25 14:29 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184884 Aug 18  2020 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  5515823 Feb  5 14:48 System.map-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5531453 Apr 13 00:17 System.map-5.8.0-50-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Apr 25 14:42 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  9716672 Apr 25 19:53 vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  9785696 Apr 13 01:47 vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       24 Apr 25 14:42 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic
```

```sh
$ uname -r

5.8.0-50-generic
```

[image: screen flickering]

Comment: Edit your question and show me either `ls -al /boot` or `uname -r`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Are you suspecting one of the recent weird kernel? I think that no one else reported this symptom in relation to the kernels. It looks like hardware failure.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes. The 5.8.0-49 and -50 kernels are causing *similar* flickering/video problems. See my other answers on this subject. Although, this one might be a hardware problem... funny enough, a reboot clears it. Waiting for a response from OP.

Comment: @heynnema I added the outputs for those commands.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes, my kernel version is exactly what you mentioned. Is there a way I can resolve this?

Comment: Go to the GRUB menu, Advanced Options menu, and select the -43 kernel, and see if that helps with the problem. If it doesn't, then you have a hardware problem.

Comment: @heynnema sure, I will try this. Thanks!

Comment: The newest kernels are suspects indeed; see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-hwe-5.8/+bug/1924624). It happened to me in two (old) laptops. Boot into an older kernel (-48 is fine) and wait for the -51 that may solve it.

Comment: I tried switching to kernel -43 but the problem still persists for me. Probably there is a hardware issue.